# Running corda in Oracle jdk1.8 is working fin but not in OpenJDK patch 1.8.392

Tags: java, corda, activemq-artemis

There is certificate chain error on OpenJDK patch 1.8.392,
but its working fine with Oracle jdk1.8.0_241,

I see that OpenJDK uses `SHA256withECDSA` in ActiveMQ Artemis client for validating certificates. (Not Working)

Oracle JDK using `SHA512withECDSA` in ActiveMQ Artemis client for validating certificate. (Working)

Is there any way I can specify JVM to use `SHA512withECDSA` algo?

Comment: You can set `enabledCipherSuites=SHA512withECDSA` on the connection URL of the JMS client. This, of course, assumes that cipher suite is available on that JVM.

Comment: @JustinBertram: that's not a ciphersuite, it's a signature algorithm (sigalg). <cue Paul Hogan> OP: _all_ Java 8 updates support _all_ {SHA2}withECDSA at JCE level. However updates 261 up support and by default offer TLSv1.3, which changes some negotiation rules including cert-selection, so 8u392 client might get a different (and possibly wrong) cert chain that 8u241 didn't get. Try turning on `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:trustmanager` and compare the resulting output. Or use Justin's method to force a non-1.3 ciphersuite like TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, nice Paul Hogan reference. Gave me a good laugh.

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085, I tried it, but seeing complete different logs for both flavours.

Comment: The log _formatting_ changes in the 'new' 1.3-supporting stack, but semantically except for some additions it should be mostly the same, especially the part showing the certs received from the server (as opposed to those loaded by trustmanager) which is what I wanted you to look at.